# Timepicker action is not fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-timepicker

This is a [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ct899/1/), In fiddle I have already include the jquery 2 and this timepicker library `http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/jquery.timepicker.js`

and the input has the id `startTime`

and I do this in a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#startTime').timepicker();
</script>
```

The problem is that nothing appear when I click on that input text though the tutorial states that this is enough to fire the timepicker dropdown.

what am i missing please?

for those who haven't worked with this library, this is its link http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/ and you can download it from here https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vsm5a/ In fiddle I simple added `jquery.timepicker.css`

Comment: you need to include `timepicker.css`

Comment: @Satpal that is great, what did you do please?

Comment: @ShaunakD I already did that in my machine but not in the jsfiddle, does that matter really? I would like to have my own style

Comment: He did the same thing!

Comment: @Satpal can I add this css file and still have my own custom style for the input please?

Comment: _I would like to have my own style_ If you want own style override the CSS. Yep you can have your own style.

Comment: @Satpal let me try that in my machine and I will update you. Many thanks for that

Comment: @Satpal I don't know why it didn't work in my machine, I added the code to this jsdiffle http://jsfiddle.net/G6znv/ could you check please? appreciate your time

Comment: @Satpal you may need to maximize the html view horizantally and vertically in order to take a good view.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vsm5a/1/

Comment: @Satpal you great man, kindly could you tell what are the changes you have made? many thanks

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli, __Nothing mate.__ Just updated HTML & CSS from [Your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G6znv/) in [My Previous Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vsm5a/)

Comment: @Satpal please how am i suppose to know the difference between the two jsdiffle please? kindly could you describe more? I tried to see the difference, there is not :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56098/discussion-between-satpal-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `jquery.timepicker.css` file.

You should use document-ready handler. like

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#startTime').timepicker(); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vsm5a/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/phpdeveloperrahul/ct899/6/):

You need to include all the below mentioned files for the plugin to work. You might be missing some.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
bootstrap-datepicker.js
bootstrap-datepicker.css
jquery.timepicker.js
query.timepicker.css
```

JS:

```
$('#startTime').timepicker();
```

Comment: according to @Satpal, the needed files is `jquery.timepicker.css` and that is correct because he gave me a working jsfiddle but I included that css file but still have the problem here is a jsdfille to the code http://jsfiddle.net/G6znv/ you may need to maximize the html view in order to take a good view

Comment: I think you forgot to initialize as $('#startTime').timepicker(); In you fiddle I just put this code and it was working !

Comment: You need to include jquery version file: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: In JSFIDDLE under the title "Frameworks & Extensions" select jquery1.7.2 and then try !

Comment: +1 to your efforts, but there is another guy helped me .thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#startTime').timepicker({dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', maxDate: '@DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")' });
});
</script>
```